# ARM listKeys() Function - How to retrieve OMS/OpsInsight Workspace keys?

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-rm-template

As part of a template I want to retrieve the SharedKeys of an OMS / Operational Insights Workspace, rather than having to pass it in as a parameter.

Is this possible? I'm following the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#listkeys)

It does not appear that the `Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/` resource provider has any `list*` provider operations, and I can't find any reference for other:

```
Get-AzureRmProviderOperation -OperationSearchString *  | where {$_.Operation -like "*operational*sharedkeys*"} | FT Operation

Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/sharedKeys/action
```

My desired usage:

```
"variables": { workspaceKey: "[listKeys(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-05-01-preview').primarySharedKey]" }
```

In the meantime, assuming this isn't actually supported, I added [a request for it on the Log Analytics UserVoice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics/suggestions/13903617-support-for-the-resource-function-listkeys)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per Ryan Jones](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#comment-2693696815), `[listKeys()]` against the OMS Workspace will work as expected and return a JSON object with `primarySharedKey` & `secondarySharedKey` properties:

```
"outputs": {
    "listKeys": {
        "value": "[listKeys(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview')]",
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

yields:

```
{
    "primarySharedKey":"",
    "secondarySharedKey":""
}
```

---

### Important Caveat:

> listKeys() can not be specified in the `variables` section of an ARM template, since it derives its value from a runtime state.
>
> [See this blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-multiple/#creating-multiple-data-disks-for-a-virtual-machine) for how to use a Linked Template, specified as a resource, in order to retrieve the output value and assign it to a property in another resource.

Alternatively, you can use it directly. Here is my final template:

***(don't actually keep the keys in the output!)***

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "workspaceResourceId": { "type": "string" },
    "virtualMachines": { "type": "array" }
  },
  "variables": {
    "extensionType": {
      "Windows": "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",
      "Linux": "OmsAgentForLinux"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "copy": {
        "name": "VMMonitoringExtensionsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('virtualMachines'))]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('virtualMachines')[copyIndex()].location]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines')[copyIndex()].name, '/Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring')]",
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
        "type": "[variables('extensionType')[parameters('virtualMachines')[copyIndex()].osType]]",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "workspaceId": "[reference(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview').customerId]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "workspaceKey": "[listKeys(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview').primarySharedKey]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "workspaceCustomerId": {
      "value": "[reference(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview').customerId]",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "workspacePrimarySharedKey": {
      "value": "[listKeys(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview').primarySharedKey]",
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "workspaceSecondarySharedKey": {
      "value": "[listKeys(parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-11-01-preview').secondarySharedKey]",
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  }
}
```

The array parameter `virtualMachines` follows this schema:

```
[
    { "name": "", "location": "", "osType": "" }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

listKeys requires that you put the resource type in. So have you tried this?

```
"variables": { workspaceKey: "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', parameters('workspaceResourceId'), '2015-05-01-preview').primarySharedKey]" }
```

Unfortunately, atm there is nothing at all in the [Azure quickstart repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Microsoft.OperationalInsights%22&type=Code) on that resource so I'm not 100% sure...

But passing it in as a parameter would be fine. You could do this... In your deployment script, before you run New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment, create/use existing workspace, get key, pass in as param, create primarySharedKey as a param in the template:

```
$workSpace = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $workSpaceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($workSpace -eq $null){
New-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $workSpaceName -Location $Location
}

$keys = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspaceSharedKeys -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $workSpaceName

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment <other stuff here> -primarySharedKey $keys.PrimarySharedKey
```

Comment: the resource type is needed as a parameter to the `resourceId()` function, for use when you have the name, but not the Id of the type. In this case, `workspaceResourceId` would already be the value from the output of the `resourceId()` funciton: `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}`

Comment: With that said, The keys I'm after are actually members of the SharedKeys object beneath the Workspace. It's unclear whether the `/actions/` operation infers a range of actions (including a list* one), or what.

Comment: also important: `listKeys()` cannot be used in the `variables` section - only `outputs`. See my answer for details on how to get around this.